# How can we denote the following function in terms of big-O notation?

Tags: algorithm, function, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have got a function and want to denote it in terms of bigO notation.

f(n) = log<sub>4</sub>n+n*(1/3). Is this function O(n)? Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the * in your formula a multiplication or a power-of?

Comment: Suggest moving to the Maths SO.

Comment: it is a multiplication

Comment: Yes this is in O(n); to convince yourself, remember than log n < n for all positives and consider the definition of O(n).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

> If a function f(n) can be written as a finite sum of other functions, then the fastest growing one determines the order of f(n).

Between `log4(n)` and `1/3 n` the fastest growing one is `1/3 n`, and

```
O(1/3 n) = O(n)
```

So `f(n)` is `O(n)`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is O(1) , because the calculation can be done on same time no matter how big the n is.